# Prompt for saving files in Javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have found many examples of saving files to disk in Javascript/Jquery but none of them showed how to have the save file prompt so the user can easily choose where to save it and what to name it. I was wondering if it is possible.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pzvkkrz9/

Comment: that doesnt prompt the user